# Flutter Listview.Builder inside bottom sheet widget not loading data on load

Tags: flutter, dart

The below code does not display any data when the bottomsheet loads. Once the bottomsheet is loaded if I do a save operation on the code editor it loads the data. What am I missing here?

I have a bottomsheet widget which is invoked using a button.

```
_showBottomSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const Contacts();
      },
    );
  }
```

The above code loads up the Contacts widget that has a Listview.builder in it which is below.

```
class Contacts extends StatefulWidget {
  const Contacts({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ContactsState createState() => _ContactsState();
}

class _ContactsState extends State<Contacts> {
  List<PhoneBookContact> phoneBookContacts1 = [];
  List<PhoneBookContact> phoneBookContacts2 = [];
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    loadContacts();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future loadContacts() async {
    ///somecode to gather data for the listview builder
    ///populates the phoneBookContacts1 & phoneBookContacts2 lists
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      const Text('Contacts Set 1'),
      displayPhoneBookContacts(phoneBookContacts1),
      const Text('Contacts Set 2'),
      displayPhoneBookContacts(phoneBookContacts2),
    ]);
  }

  Widget displayPhoneBookContacts(phoneBookContacts) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: phoneBookContacts.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: ListTile(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              title: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(phoneBookContacts[index].phoneBookContact.toString()),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  ListView.separated(
                    physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: phoneBookContacts[index].contactNumbers!.length,
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        const Divider(),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int phoneIndex) {
                      return InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(phoneBookContacts[index]
                                .contactNumbers![phoneIndex]
                                .phone),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you calling `setState` in `loadContacts`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, I was not, I did, now it works as expected. Thanks Yeasin. Could you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't prefer using `FutureBuilder` inside `StatefulWidget`., it  will recall the API(`future`) on every `setState`. As for comment it is missing `setState` after initializing the data.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadContacts();
  }

  Future loadContacts() async {
    ///somecode to gather data for the listview builder
    ///populates the phoneBookContacts1 & phoneBookContacts2

    if(mounted){ 
// if widget build then setState call.if not we don't need to call setState
// for every initstate data loading, we have to ensure it if widget is build or not. most of the case user close screen when data loading, then error happens

      setState(() {});// make sure to call setState
     }
  
}
```

Comment: use mounted before setState

Comment: feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because function `initState()` don't await your `loadContacts()`, data loaded after function `build()`.

You need use FutureBuilder class to rebuild ListView widget after load data

Example:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: loadContacts(),
    builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
         } else {
            return Container(
                child: ListView.builder(                                                  
                    itemCount: _faouriteList.length,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Text('${_faouriteList[index].title}');                                           
                    }
                )
            );
         }
     }
)
```

Comment: Hello Saitoh, I am loading the data on the initstate method of the widget which I thought would only call the method after the method is finished executing.

Comment: I tried this code void initState() {
    pullContactsData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void pullContactsData() async {
    await fetchSupabaseContactsAndCheckWithPhoneBookContacts();
  }

Comment: still not loading

Comment: if you await all function  loadContacts() like this: "await  loadContacts()" 
then main function call the method after the method is finished executing.

but initState() can't await then  you must use FutureBuilder

Comment: Thats why I created another method just to await and then call that method from inistate() like in the snippet above, that also is not working.

Comment: Yeb. but initState() not await your another method you created , you can print all step method run in you print you will see